# Symfony2 ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to put my application on a new server, the configuration is the same as the development server and at the development server it runs fine. But when I go to the live server, the first page works fine but the second page shows an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error. This has never occurred to me.

The server is an amazon ec2 Debian 7 server with apache2.2.22 and PHP 5.4.4-14+deb7u7, there is no mysql database because the application connects to a mssql database within the same cluster. The symfony version is 2.4.2

I've searched the internet for a solution but all you get that's it's apc and a known bug at apc but I don't use apc for this application. I also don't use the following modules:

- APC
- xCache
- suhosin
- xDebug

The apache logs doesn't show anything weird and the Symfony2 logs also.

I'm kind of lost here so if anyone knows a solution please tell.

Comment: The same error message I saw in Chrome browser due to using opcache with Symfony2. Firefox would show "The connection was reset" error message. Make sure whether you use any PHP accelerator (apc, opcache,...), and you should try to reset it's cache.

Comment: @DjuroMandinic tried that no luck, complete reinstall of the server and starting from scratch did the job ;) Thanks for the reply anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I did a complete reinstall of the server and that did the job, no clue where it went wrong the last time...